# Adhering to the OOP Dry principle

Tags: jquery, dry

I am just learning how to use JQuery, and I am lost in how to condense my code and make it adhere to the OOP dry principle.
The goal is to make four images move left when one is clicked on.
I did this in four statements, but I am wondering how to go about make in more modular.

If anyone as an idea that could lead me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.

```
var clix = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    $("#head").click(function () {
        if (headclix < 9) {
            $("#head").animate({
                left: "-=367px"
            }, 500);
            headclix += 1;
        } else {
            $("#head").animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 500);
            headclix = 0;
        }
    });

    $("#eyes").click(function () {
        if (eyeclix < 9) {
            $("#eyes").animate({
                left: "-=367px"
            }, 500);
            eyeclix += 1;
        } else {
            $("#eyes").animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 500);
            eyeclix = 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: OOP and DRY are two different principles.

Comment: What is the `clix` array for?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question, this question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help). If you wish for a peer review to improve *all* aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: Originally, I have four variables that worked as counters.  So each time a user clicked on a image, the image would cycle left to the next image.  I thought an array would work in place of them.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of targeting specific IDs, give all the elements the same `class`. Then you can bind the handler to the class, and use `$(this)` to refer to the element that was clicked on. And instead of using global variables like `headclix`, you can use `$(this).data()` to associate the click count with the element.

```
$(".animated").click(function() {
    var clix = $(this).data("clix") || 0;
    if (clix < 9) {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "-=367px"
        }, 500).data("clix", clix + 1);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 500).data("clix", 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best solution, but it's a better way to do, doing:

```
var the_click_function = function(){
    //some code
}
```

and fire the event as:

```
$("#eyes").click(the_click_function);
$("#head").click(the_click_function);
...
```

or

```
$("#head, #eyes").click(the_click_function);
```

Obviously, this is an example code, always you can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that "generates" the callback functions. This function takes advantage of closure to keep the counter.

You could make this function customizable: it could take different parameters in order to make the callback more customizable. Also, this parameters could have "default" values ([jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/) style, for instance).

These are just ideas to make your code more reusable and avoid code duplication. JS is very flexible in this regard and there are a lot of patterns and ways of doing things that encourage reusability.

For instance:

```js
function eventCallbackGen(conf) {
  var counter = 0;
  return function() {
    var lessThanMax = counter < conf.maxCount;
    conf.$el.animate({
      left: lessThanMax ? "-=" + conf.decreasePixels + "px" : conf.startingPoint + "px"
    }, conf.animationTime);
    counter = lessThanMax ? (counter + 1) : 0;
  };
}

var $head = $("#head"),
  $eyes = $("#eyes");

$head.click(eventCallbackGen({
  $el: $head,
  maxCount: 9,
  decreasePixels: 367,
  startingPoint: 0,
  animationTime: 500
}));

$eyes.click(eventCallbackGen({
  $el: $eyes,
  maxCount: 9,
  decreasePixels: 367,
  startingPoint: 0,
  animationTime: 500
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```